# Write a csv file with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, csv, puppeteer

I want to write a csv file for my outputs after scraping with puppeteer i've tried different methods but i can't get a result here's the part of the code of data that i want to export to a csv file.

```
 async function main(){

 const allinks = await getLinks();
 //console.log(allinks);
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
 


    for (let link of allinks){
     const data = await getInfoscrape(link,page);
    

   }
  } main();
```

and my data structure is :
Poste
Contrat
Salaire
Diplome
Experience
Travail
Description

for the result i have this as a json , so i want to write in csv file
'''

```js
{
    Poste: 'Lead Développeur',
    Contrat: 'CDI ',
    Salaire: 'Salaire entre 65K € et 75K €',
    Diplome: 'Bac +5 / Master',
    Experience: '> 3 ans',
    Travail: 'Télétravail partiel possible',
    Description: 'En tant que Lead Développeur(se), tu seras chargé(e) de mentorer des développeurs de Galadrim dans l’objectif de les faire progresser. Les tâches typiques du poste sont les suivantes :faire des code reviews sur différents projets\n' +
      'participer au choix des technologies et de l’architecture sur les nouveaux projets\n' +
      'faire des sessions de pair-programming avec les développeurs\n' +
      'aider à la résolution des problèmes les plus complexes\n' +
      'faire de la veille technique\n' +
      'Une application mobile de rencontres\n' +
      'Un moteur de réservation en ligne pour des parcours de golf\n' +
      'Un site web de commande de box par abonnement pour un grand groupe de cosmétiques\n' +
      'Un logiciel de caisse'
  },
```

```
  '''
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including a sample of the HTML you're scraping and the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

I use Node's built-in "fs" module to write .csv.

Something like this:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
let data = fs.readFileSync("./data.json") // an array of objects
data = JSON.parse(data);

let csv = "locationPoint\taddress\tschedule\tfarmName\n";

data.forEach( ferme => {
  csv += ferme.locationPoint + `\t`;
  csv += ferme.fullAddress + `\t`;
  csv += ferme.schedule + `\t`;
  csv += ferme.farmName + "\n";
})

console.log('@success', csv);
fs.writeFileSync("fermes.csv", csv)
```

Note that in my example, I'm using tabs instead of commas; my data is prone to contain commas.

For your case, you'd replace :

```js
let csv = "locationPoint\taddress\tschedule\tfarmName\n";
```

with:

```js
let csv = "Poste\tContrat\tSalaire\tDiplome\tExperience\tTravail\tDescription\n";
```

And, similarly for the rest of the values in the forEach loop.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your ansewr. I tried to understand your code, Can you tell me please do you have a file.json that contains all your data? because in my case the result that i attached is just a console.log.

Comment: Yes, I do have a file called data.json. It's an array of JSON objects.